# How would I write a RewriteRule to make redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite the html and xml files and directories to the pagename query string using .htaccess file. like this :

mysubsite/category_1/category_2/
mysubsite/category_1/category_2/file1.html
mysubsite/category_1/category_2/file2.152.html

index.php?pagename=category_1/category_2/
index.php?pagename=category_1/category_2/file1.html
index.php?pagename=category_1/category_2/file1.152.html

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You have

mysubsite/category_1/category_2/ mysubsite/category_1/category_2/file1.html mysubsite/category_1/category_2/file2.152.html

and

index.php?pagename=category_1/category_2/ index.php?pagename=category_1/category_2/file1.html index.php?pagename=category_1/category_2/file1.152.html

And I'm supposing that you meant:

mysubsite/category_1/category_2/

mysubsite/category_1/category_2/file1.html

mysubsite/category_1/category_2/file2.152.html

and

index.php?pagename=category_1/category_2/

index.php?pagename=category_1/category_2/file1.html

index.php?pagename=category_1/category_2/file1.152.html

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^mysubsite/(.*) index.php?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```